# How to fire event GTM in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to fire a Google Tag Manager event after a click. I have to pass some variables to that event and then call it, but it's not working.

I have to do it in the JavaScript code, after the Google Analytics transaction.
This is what I did, but can not see if fires or not:

```
GoogleAnalyticsTransaction(data);

GTMEventTransaction(data)


function GTMEventTransaction(data) {
  var gtmDataLayer = gtmDataLayer || [];
  gtmDataLayer.push({'id':data.ID});
  gtmDataLayer.push({'productid':data.ProductID});
  gtmDataLayer.push({'product_price':data.Price});
  gtmDataLayer.push({'event':'Conversion'});
}
```

I am in the preview mode of the GTM but when I click my button nothing happens. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You use "gtmDataLayer" name instead default dataLayer name. Did you rembemer first to rename "dataLayer" in default google tag manager implementation code? Or second (assuming that your datalayer name is correct) try to change: var gtmDataLayer = gtmDataLayer || []; to var gtmDataLayer = window.gtmDataLayer || [];

Comment: Did you remember to create your event tag in GTM that is triggered by your `event` "Conversion"?

Comment: Yes I did, I have the event on the GTM